# Common Post Action with multiple Submit buttons

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a situation where I have three Submit buttons and there is one value that changes in each Submit-Post: `ActionType`: `1`, `2`, or `3`

I feel this is too much redundant code.

```csharp
    public async Task<IActionResult> Action(long letterId)
    {
        ViewData["ActionError"] = "";

        var letter = await service.GetLetterFlatByIdAsync(letterId);

        if (letter?.KtaCurrentApprover == currentUser.Id)
            return View(new ApproverActionModel
            {
                LetterId = letterId,
                Letter   = letter
            });

        ViewData["ActionError"] = "You are not assigned the current action";
        return View(null);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ActionApprove(ApproverActionModel model)
    {
        model.Letter = (await service.GetLetterFlatByIdAsync(model.LetterId))!;

        ModelState.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Comments))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Comments", "Please provide appropriate comments before submitting.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return RedirectToAction("Action", model);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "ActionType", 1 },
            { "ActionData", model.Comments },
            { "ActionTakenBy", currentUser.Id },
            { "ModifiedPayload", model.Letter }
        };

        await service.ActionAsync(model.LetterId, parameters);

        return RedirectToAction("MyList");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ActionInfo(ApproverActionModel model)
    {
        model.Letter = (await service.GetLetterFlatByIdAsync(model.LetterId))!;

        ModelState.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Comments))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Comments", "Please provide appropriate comments before submitting.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return RedirectToAction("Action", model);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "ActionType", 3 },
            { "ActionData", model.Comments },
            { "ActionTakenBy", currentUser.Id },
            { "ModifiedPayload", model.Letter }
        };

        await service.ActionAsync(model.LetterId, parameters);

        return RedirectToAction("MyList");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ActionReject(ApproverActionModel model)
    {
        model.Letter = (await service.GetLetterFlatByIdAsync(model.LetterId))!;

        ModelState.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Comments))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Comments", "Please provide appropriate comments before submitting.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return RedirectToAction("Action", model);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "ActionType", 2 },
            { "ActionData", model.Comments },
            { "ActionTakenBy", currentUser.Id },
            { "ModifiedPayload", model.Letter }
        };

        await service.ActionAsync(model.LetterId, parameters);

        return RedirectToAction("MyList");
    }
```

Is there a way to have a single Post Handler and somehow manage to identify the submit button to infer the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered sending the value of the submit button to the controller for judgment?

Like this:

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ActionReject(ApproverActionModel model, string ButtonValue)
{
            int ActionType;
            if (ButtonValue == "button1")
            {
                ActionType = 1;
            }
            else if (ButtonValue == "button2")
            {
                ActionType = 2;
            }
            else 
            {
                ActionType = 3;
            }

            //.....

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "ActionType", ActionType },
                { "ActionData", model.Comments },
                { "ActionTakenBy", currentUser.Id },
                { "ModifiedPayload", model.Letter }
            };

            //......
}
```

View:

```
<form methed = "post" asp-action="ActionReject" >

    //......

    <input type="submit" name="ButtonValue" value="button1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="ButtonValue" value="button2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="ButtonValue" value="button3"/>
</form>
```

Comment: No, I didn't, sir as I didn't realize this was an option. Testing it out right now...